# Dynamically compile and add a partial class to assembly

Tags: c#

I'm trying to dynamically add properties to a partial class.  These properties will not be known at compiletime and need to be added at runtime.

I've written some code to do this, but it seems to be added two different classes instead of combining the classes.

The class compiles just fine, but as a new class.

It's worth mentioning that the original class IS a partial class, and I can combine a partial class if added as a class file at compile time.

```
const string DynamicClass = @"
public partial class activity
{   
public int? client_id { get; set; }
public int? brand_id { get; set; }
public int? financial_group_id { get; set; }
public int? financials_locked { get; set; }
public int? inv_exchange_rate_id { get; set; }
public int? fin_exchange_rate_id { get; set; }
public int? funding_acct_id { get; set; }
public int? synch_lock { get; set; }    
}
";

public static void AddDynamicMapping()
{
    var properties = typeof (activity).GetProperties(); // Check properties of class before I add the partial class
    var provider = CSharpCodeProvider.CreateProvider("c#");
    var options = new CompilerParameters();
    var assembly =
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(ex => ex.GetTypes().Any(at => at.Name == "activity"));
    var assemblyContainingNotDynamicClass = Path.GetFileName(assembly.Location);
    options.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(assemblyContainingNotDynamicClass);
    var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(options, new[] { DynamicClass });
    if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var error in results.Errors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var t = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("activity");
        var properties2 = t.GetProperties(); // Class has been compiled and has it's own properties
        properties = typeof(activity).GetProperties(); // properties of original class remain unchanged
        var i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have an already-compiled class called `activity` and you want to dynamically add members to it?  I'm pretty sure that's not possible.

Comment: So what happens in this case.  Does the assembly now have two classes with the same name?

Comment: You'll have to create a proxy. That's what some frameworks do, like NHibernate and EF. Look at [Castle Project Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/), that's what Nhibernate used up to version two.

Comment: Why aren't you using some kind of dynamic object?

Comment: @ThomasLielacher, if you mean like an expandoobject, EF won't let a codefirst class inherit from expando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to dynamically add members to an already-compiled class, but just making it `partial` certainly doesn't make a difference.  All `partial` does is allow the code to be split between multiple files, all of which must be present at compile-time.  It does not add any metadata that makes the class "extensible".  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx):

> All the parts must be available at compile time to form the final type.

Some alternatives:

- decorator pattern
- add a dictionary property to "properties" dynamically
- virtual members and sub-classing
- extension methods (note that extension *properties* are not supported at this time)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at the other options you mentioned.